# Array sorting issue in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to sort data (x) and find how many times each record is greater than any previous record. I have it starting with the the second record (index 1) in my range and then comparing to the max of values from index 0 up to i. I am having a hard time and have tried breaking it down to steps and am unsure of how it is failing? Can anyone lend any insights? Many thanks, hopefully I explained it properly.

```
def greater(x):
g=0
for i in range(len(x[1:])):
    if x[i] > np.max(x[:i]):
        g = g + 1            
return g
```

Expected result:

x=[0,1,1,5,4]
g should = 2, at record index 1,3

Comment: how many times it is greater than any previous records? I can take that to mean two entirely different things; neither of which appear to have anything to do with your code snippet. perhaps it would help to post some example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Added expected results given input array. Hopefully that explains it properly. Essentially, how many time is i greater than any value up to i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing your maing loop wrong

It should be:

```
for i in range(1,len(x)):
```

as you want to loop through values **from 1** to the **length of x**, while your code loops **from 0** to **length of x minus 1**

btw. it has nothing to do with "array comprehension"

It would be also more efficient to store the current max value instead of performing `np.max(x[:i])` (which is linear).

Comment: That appears to work, but now Python crashes with no exception errors reporting. Many thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize this with numpy as follows:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 1, 5, 4]
>>> np.count_nonzero(x[1:] > np.maximum.accumulate(x)[:-1])
2
```

To understand what's going on:

```
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(x)
array([0, 1, 1, 5, 5])
>>> x[1:] > np.maximum.accumulate(x)[:-1]
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

You can get the indices of the positions where `g` is increased with:

```
>>> np.nonzero(x[1:] > np.maximum.accumulate(x)[:-1])[0] + 1
array([1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

As lejlot said, it's not necessary to keep recalculating the maximum of all the previous list items each time -- just record the running maximum as you go through the list once. This also means that you don't need to keep reslicing the list, so you don't have to keep track of your current position in the list -- just the current item -- and therefore, you don't need `range()` or `len()`, either. This leads to a very simple implementation:

```
def greater(x):
    g = 0
    newmax = x[0]
    for i in x[1:]:
        if i > newmax:
            g += 1
            newmax = i
    return g
```

Comment: For the best answer explain your code, don't only post code.